# Signing in with Apple Sign In

Tags: ios, authentication, security, jwt

I am signing my user into my cordova/node app with Apple Sign In.

I'm using https://github.com/twogate/cordova-plugin-sign-in-with-apple and it seems to work perfectly.

Here is the code that invokes the Apple sign in flow:

```
window.cordova.plugins.SignInWithApple.signin(
  { requestedScopes: [0, 1] },
  function (succ: any) {
    console.log(succ);
  },
  function (err: any) { /* */ }
);
```

It seems to work perfectly and returns the following

```
{
  "email":"",
  "authorizationCode":"c421b3675a4b341b6964dd5ed6a00eedf.0.swxu.MlDrFsfqlqhHKbVD6PWzFw",
  "state":"",
  "identityToken":"eyJraWQiOiJZdXlYb1kiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FwcGxlaWQuYXBwbGUuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoibWUuYXVkaW9kaWFyeS5hdWRpb2RpYXJ5IiwiZXhwIjoxNjY5NTA0OTg4LCJpYXQiOjE2Njk0MTg1ODgsInN1YiI6IjAwMDY3NC4wZjYwOGM3OTkyYzM0NWU2YTcyYTFiMWU1MjQ2ZGQxMC4yMzEwIiwiY19oYXNoIjoibDhHLUliTGhMamw1N3VPYWpia0djQSIsImVtYWlsIjoiZGFyYWphdmFoZXJpYW5AZ21haWwuY29tIiwiZW1haWxfdmVyaWZpZWQiOiJ0cnVlIiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNjY5NDE4NTg4LCJub25jZV9zdXBwb3J0ZWQiOnRydWV9.o3oebWAvmLegdtie4XDTwuFvQCFvBBeW3Kn062TLqt3_2cl64OrsdoznHtiNg2EiB0k9BsGq413zS-sZGXHE0XkKKZFqxCy5xwdfXFTZbtFozDy3my0jxUZlqMOaBJxBUMhhs96khf7m0bBZ1Jd0onzIHKipePYYfazvz0zVnNhfEf3M8WyUR9jbCqbvB5Rg1Kcj6LV8u389Mt1HBYO5NB44DJb-X_h6YCqd58rZ85GXU7soiX4LRBVRjNZB4Wx7SvSqarGLO7e29tiJDLBK6HUdrO7qybUhDjl40Cd7q0OXk62NcdQhMED5YWh-E0nUA7PMJVDAdEpiAXWp_Ihdfg",
  "fullName":{
    "nickname":"",
    "phoneticRepresentation":{},
    "middleName":"",
    "familyName":"",
    "namePrefix":"",
    "givenName":"",
    "nameSuffix":""
  },
  "user":"000674.0f608c7992c345e6a72a1b1e5246dd10.2310"
}
```

The `identityToken` above looks like [this](https://jwt.io/#debugger-io?token=eyJraWQiOiJZdXlYb1kiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FwcGxlaWQuYXBwbGUuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoibWUuYXVkaW9kaWFyeS5hdWRpb2RpYXJ5IiwiZXhwIjoxNjY5NTA0OTg4LCJpYXQiOjE2Njk0MTg1ODgsInN1YiI6IjAwMDY3NC4wZjYwOGM3OTkyYzM0NWU2YTcyYTFiMWU1MjQ2ZGQxMC4yMzEwIiwiY19oYXNoIjoibDhHLUliTGhMamw1N3VPYWpia0djQSIsImVtYWlsIjoiZGFyYWphdmFoZXJpYW5AZ21haWwuY29tIiwiZW1haWxfdmVyaWZpZWQiOiJ0cnVlIiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNjY5NDE4NTg4LCJub25jZV9zdXBwb3J0ZWQiOnRydWV9.o3oebWAvmLegdtie4XDTwuFvQCFvBBeW3Kn062TLqt3_2cl64OrsdoznHtiNg2EiB0k9BsGq413zS-sZGXHE0XkKKZFqxCy5xwdfXFTZbtFozDy3my0jxUZlqMOaBJxBUMhhs96khf7m0bBZ1Jd0onzIHKipePYYfazvz0zVnNhfEf3M8WyUR9jbCqbvB5Rg1Kcj6LV8u389Mt1HBYO5NB44DJb-X_h6YCqd58rZ85GXU7soiX4LRBVRjNZB4Wx7SvSqarGLO7e29tiJDLBK6HUdrO7qybUhDjl40Cd7q0OXk62NcdQhMED5YWh-E0nUA7PMJVDAdEpiAXWp_Ihdfg&publicKey=%7B%0A%20%20%22e%22%3A%20%22AQAB%22%2C%0A%20%20%22kty%22%3A%20%22RSA%22%2C%0A%20%20%22n%22%3A%20%221JiU4l3YCeT4o0gVmxGTEK1IXR-Ghdg5Bzka12tzmtdCxU00ChH66aV-4HRBjF1t95IsaeHeDFRgmF0lJbTDTqa6_VZo2hc0zTiUAsGLacN6slePvDcR1IMucQGtPP5tGhIbU-HKabsKOFdD4VQ5PCXifjpN9R-1qOR571BxCAl4u1kUUIePAAJcBcqGRFSI_I1j_jbN3gflK_8ZNmgnPrXA0kZXzj1I7ZHgekGbZoxmDrzYm2zmja1MsE5A_JX7itBYnlR41LOtvLRCNtw7K3EFlbfB6hkPL-Swk5XNGbWZdTROmaTNzJhV-lWT0gGm6V1qWAK2qOZoIDa_3Ud0Gw%22%0A%7D) on JWT.io.

I seem to have all the info I need in the identity token, so my question is how can I ensure this token is valid and comes from apple? If I make an endpoint called `/register-with-apple`, and pass that token in, how can I be sure it isn't faked? JWT.io have a method of verifying the signature, but I don't really get it, and could I not make my own JWT pretty easily with a valid signature that is independent of Apple's?

I just don't really understand how I am supposed to use this result to sign my user in/create an account.

I tried looking up how to perhaps verify the token, but people generally say this is done on the server. I have no problem passing the token to the server and validating it, but I don't see how it's not very easy to forge. i.e. if someone does sign in using Apple, and I make a token with a name and email, and pass it to my endpoint. Then my endpoint will just log them in as normal.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_rest_api/verifying_a_user  If you validate the signature using Apple's key then no one can forge a JWT since they can't sign it with Apple's key

Comment: Specifically the `kid` in the token identifies the key you should use to validate the signature